# How do I allow function #2 to run only after function #1 is complete, but without triggering function #2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I have 2 functions, onTouchStart and onTouchEnd, where onTouchEnd uses a state variable that onTouchStart sets. I'm worried that the onTouchEnd function could read the wrong value of a state variable because onTouchStart might not have finished setting the state. The main problem is that I don't want onTouchEnd to get triggered every time onTouchStart finishes, but need onTouchStart to set the state-stored variable to the correct value before onTouchEnd executes.

```
onTouchStart(){
   this.setState({
      randomBool: true   
   }); 
}

onTouchEnd(){
   console.log("randomBool should be true: " + this.state.randomBool);

   //then some stuff here
}
```

Comment: do you control the caller of these functions?

Comment: onTouchStart gets executed when a user presses on an element, and onTouchEnd gets executed when a user releases the element.

Comment: would it be better to put the lines from //then some stuff here in onTouchStart? this way you don't need onTouchEnd since you mentioned you don't want it to get triggered everytime and can control when you want to do stuff? or move everything to onTouchEnd

Comment: What I should have mentioned is that in my actual project there are multiple elements to press on. onTouchStart contains data on which element was pressed down on, and onTouchEnd contains data on which element was released on. But I need to have the initial data on which element was first pressed to so that onTouchEnd can "do some stuff" with that element in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a check followed by `setTimeout`:

```
onTouchEnd(){
  if (!this.state.randomBool)
    setTimeout(this.onTouchEnd, 10);

  //then some stuff here
}
```

If needed you can also pass parameters into the "recursive" call: `setTimeout(() => this.onTouchEnd(v1, v2), 10);`

Comment: Yea i guess there's no way to just add the function to a queue or something... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this deterministically, you need some state to which you can write synchronously, and you need something to indicate that setState has completed.

(I'm making an assumption here that setState provides this indication in the form of a promise).

In the snippet below, hold the mouse down for less than a second, and then try again for more than a second...

```js
document.getElementById("touchMe").addEventListener('mousedown', onTouchStart);
document.getElementById("touchMe").addEventListener('mouseup', onTouchEnd);

let state;  // assuming we can only read and write this async...

// ...with this getter and setter
async function setState(object) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      state = object
      resolve()
    }, 1000);
  })
}

async function getState() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(state)
    }, 1000);
  })
}

// BUT, we can write this synchronously
let settingState = false;

function onTouchStart() {
  settingState = true;
  setState({ someBool: true }).then(() => {
    settingState = false;
  })
}

function onTouchEnd() {
  if (settingState) {
    console.log("giving up, because we're busy writing state");
    return;
  }
  console.log("we can get state now");
  getState().then(state => console.log(state));
  
}
```

```html
<div id="touchMe" style="background-color:yellow;">Touch Me</div>
```